Passing generic messes up computed return type
I have a function (foo) which returns different type based on the params and it works fine. More specifically if the function is called with foo({objFormat: true}) the function should return type {data: string} instead of string.
But when i introduce one more generic to the function (foo2) through which the caller can pass his desired return type (useful for API calls) the computation of the return type based on the params stops working.
Why is this happening and can we bypass it somehow?
type Props = {
  brand?: string;
  objFormat?: boolean;
}

function foo
<
P extends Props = Props, 
R = P extends {objFormat: true} ? {data: string} : string
>
(params?: P): R {
  if (params?.objFormat) {
    return {data: "gg"} as R;
  }
  return "gg" as R
}

const fooRes = foo({objFormat: true}); // CORRECT
const fooRes2 = foo({objFormat: false}); // CORRECT

function foo2
<
T, 
P extends Props = Props, 
R = P extends {objFormat: true} ? {data: T} : T
>
(params?: P): R {
  if (params?.objFormat) {
    return {data: 5} as R;
  }
  return 5 as R
}

const foo2Res = foo2<number>({objFormat: true}); // WRONG
const foo2Res2 = foo2<number>({objFormat: false}); // CORRECT


It looks like that TS does not infer more specific type from actual argument type if a type variable was given default type.
So I think we might delay its condition check (function body was stripped):
type Props = {
  brand?: string;
  objFormat?: boolean;
}

declare function foo<
    P extends Props = Props, 
    R = P extends {objFormat: true} ? {data: string} : string
>(params?: P): R;

{
    const a: string = foo();
}
const fooRes: { data: string } = foo({objFormat: true});
const fooRes2: string = foo({objFormat: false});

declare function foo2<
    T, 
    const PP = Props
>(params?: PP):
    PP extends Props 
    ? PP extends {objFormat: true} 
        ? {data: T}
        : T
    : PP extends undefined 
        ? T
        : never;

const foo2Res: { data: number } = foo2({objFormat: true});
const foo2Res2: number = foo2({objFormat: false});

